# What is the command structure to open a new terminal and execute the given set on commands on this new terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator

#### I am on Linux Mint 19.03

First of all, I can assure you that I have read most of the possible questions you might think this question of mine is a duplicate of.

Now, I basically want to type something in my terminal window to open a new terminal window and execute the commands.

Something like this:

```
[the part I am asking of] "echo $PATH; read"
```

This code should do open a new terminal, the $PATH variable should be displayed and read is just for halting the terminal.

I tried `x-terminal-emulator -e` or `x-terminal-emulator -c` or `-x` but I could never achieve to do this correctly.
All answers on this SE on the similar questions are both old answers and were using -e or -x but it says that those options are deprecated.

So, what is the most proper way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: My [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575204/308316) is not using `-e` or `-x` ;-). The problem with `-e` in gnome-terminal and alike is that they don't pass the (single!) argument to a shell via `-c` but are actually parsing it themselves, and doing it BADLY. That's why the accepted answer works, because it's using a real shell. `x-terminal-emulator -- sh -c 'echo $PATH; read'` would've worked, too, with less quote clutter.

Comment: Notice that `-e` is still the only way you could pass a command to terminal emulators like `xterm` or `mlterm` (and even those have [different, strange ideas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484566/308316) of what the arguments after `-e` mean), so there's no general solution.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for the help. However, first, your answer scares me(a real beginner :d) and second, your suggestion does not work, a new terminal pops up but nothing is printed there, just like opening a new terminal, just like typing just `x-terminal-emulator`

Comment: There's nothing to be scared of, it won't eat you. My suggestion works with `bash` instead of `sh` (which on debian and alike is a different shell, `dash`, where the `read` without a variable name is an error) `x-terminal-emulator -- bash -c 'echo $PATH; read'`. Sorry for that, I should've tested it.

Comment: @mosvy actually, I had done that replacement already, but did not change anything. Just tried again after your recent comment, again, not working. Are you able to run it for sure? If so, then I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` is wrapper. What terminal emulator exactly does it wrap to on your system? Does it still not work if you run it directly as `gnome-terminal` or `mate-terminal`?

Comment: `muyustan@mint:~$ update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator
x-terminal-emulator - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
  link x-terminal-emulator is /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-terminal-emulator.1.gz
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper - priority 40
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz`

Comment: @mosvy I am not sure if it wil be helpful but I shared some update-alternatives output above, it is not the best format to read, however, it looks like it was pointing to `gnome-terminal`, which I also was thinking so. However, surprisingly, replacing `x-terminal-emulator` with `gnome-terminal`, it worked. I did not understand why actually. A more readable output by the way : `muyustan@mint:~$ update-alternatives --list x-terminal-emulator` --> 
`/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`

Comment: It seems that `x-terminal-emulator` (which is a perl wrapper), does not support the `gnome-terminal -- cmd and args` form which is "recommended" new way. Your first attempt failed for the same reason as my first suggestion -- that wrapper tries to be smart and turns the `-e cmd` into `sh -c cmd`, but the default `sh` on your system doesn't support `read` without an argument. If you used `read f` in the 1st place, your attempt would've worked.

Comment: To summarize, either `x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c '...'` or `gnome-terminal -- bash -c '...'` will work, but `x-terminal-emulator -e '...'` or `gnome-terminal -e '...'` will get you into trouble if the `'...'` is anything but a simple `program arguments...` command.

Comment: @mosvy you are so right, `muyustan@mint:~$ sh`
`$ read`
`sh: 1: read: arg count` each line seperated by a space. Thanks for all help. You should consider to compile these comments in an answer, it might be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x-terminal-emulator` doesn't start a shell by itself. This leafs just executables to be started with the `-e` option.

While `echo` is available as an executable (`/bin/echo`), `read` as a `bash` internal command will fail without `bash`. Therefore the output in the new window is done faster than it takes to open the window and as `read` fails, the window is closed before you see it.

This will do the trick:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c 'echo $PATH; read'"
```

Now `x-terminal-emulator` starts a `bash` shell which then will execute `echo $PATH; read`. As `echo` and specially `read` now are available as `bash` internal commands, the `read` command will not fail and wait for an input, which keeps the window open until a key is pressed.

Comment: Note that with the combination of single and double quotes that you use, the `$HOME` variable will be expanded _before_  `x-terminal-emulator` is executed.

Comment: @Kusalananda did you mean the $PATH variable?

Comment: Duh, yes, sorry. But I don't know if it actually matters or not when it is expanded, unless they need to compare its value with what it is in the current shell.

Comment: thanks! This works as desired. A bit detailed explanation on how it works would make this answer much better, though.

Comment: yes! after your edit, now I understand the need of using `bash` so, if no bash internal command will be used, then is `bash -c` part not a must to have?

Comment: correct. `x-terminal-emulator -e "vi /tmp/file.txt"` will start vi in a new window and open /tmp/file.txt to be created or edited.